# Sequence $1, \frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{6},\frac{1}{8},\frac{7}{90},\frac{19}{288},\frac{41}{840},\frac{751}{17280}$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, polynomials

Let $d\geq 0$ be a degree. Using the fact that the $L_1$ norm and the
$L_{\infty}$ norm are equivalent on the finite-dimensional space of polynomials
of degree $\leq d$, we see that there is a constant $c_d>0$ such that

$$\int_{[0,1]}f \geq c_df(0)$$

whenever $f\in{\mathbb R}[x]$ with degree $d$ and $f\geq 0$ on $[0,1]$.

I have computed the optimal value for $c_d$  for $d\leq 7$ :

$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
d & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
\hline
c_d & 1 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{8} & \frac{7}{90} 
& \frac{19}{288} & \frac{41}{840} & \frac{751}{17280} \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

Is this sequence already known ?
I found those values of $c_d$ by showing that $\int_{[0,1]}f$ can be written as a nonnegative linear combination of the $f(\frac{k}{d})$ for $0\leq k\leq d$, with the coefficient before $f(0)$ equal to $c_d$. This method breaks down for $d=8$ (and in fact, seems to break down for practically all $d\geq 8$) because negative coefficients appear in the decomposition.

Comment: See https://oeis.org/A100620 and https://oeis.org/A002176